# can't see what I'm writing on a web form

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser

Samsung I9001, android 2.3.6.

If there is a multiline web form, using landscape mode, I'm just seeing the empty part of the web form while I'm using the on screen keyboard.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious:

- try portrait mode
- use a hardware keyboard
- get a device with a bigger screen (ouch -- yeah, I stop this ;)

The not-so-obvious:

- try an alternate keyboard, which consumes less space or offers transparency:

  - [A.I.type Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android): According to the screenshots, it offers transparency
  - [FloatNSplit Tablet Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android.tablet): The name suggests already it's for tablets only -- but allows to split the keyboard and move it around
  - [TransparentKeyboard Froyo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.si.inputmethod.transparent_keyboard_froyo): Again, as the name suggests, another transparent keyboard

There might be more solutions (and certainly more alternative keyboards) available, so this list is far from being complete...